# Mysql sum column according to another column

Tags: mysql

This is my table data from my `Mysql` Table

```
t_Id  t_Type  t_Date      t_acd_Id  t_acc_Id  t_Amount  t_Desc  t_u_Id    c_Id  
------  ------  ----------  --------  --------  --------  ------  ------  --------
     1       0  2016-01-26       266        29  400.00                 1         1
     2       0  2016-01-27       266        29  160.00                 1         1
     3       1  2016-01-28        29       266  83.30                  1         1
     4       2  2016-01-27        29       272  400.00                 1         1
     5       0  2016-01-27       266       272  300.00                 1         1
     6       1  2016-01-28       272        22  20.00                  1         1
```

I Want my result like

```
     accout_Id  rec_Amount  pay_Amount 
        ------  ----------  ----------  
            29      483.30      560.00
```

where `rec_Amount` is sum of `t_acd_Id` and `pay_Amount` is sum of `t_acc_Id`

How to get this result?

My current query 
`SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(t_Amount) FROM tbl_transactions  WHERE`t_acd_Id`= 29) AS rec_Amount, 
(SELECT SUM(t_Amount) FROM tbl_transactions WHERE`t_acc_Id`= 29) AS pay_Amount 
FROM tbl_transactions`

which gives multiple rows

Comment: How do you plan to handle the `t_acd_Id` for value `266`?  Would the `rec_Amount` be `860` in this case?  Can you elaborate on your rules for aggregating the id values?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated my question with my current query,

Comment: Try grouping by `account_Id`.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with this query? as i have checked it manually.

```
SELECT t4.t_acd_Id as accout_Id ,sum(t4.t_Amount) as rec_Amount, (SELECT SUM(t_Amount) from table4 WHERE t_acc_Id =t4.t_acd_Id) as pay_Amount FROM `table4` as t4 WHERE t4.t_acd_Id IN (29,266) GROUP BY t4.t_acd_Id
```

Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. It shows with all account_Id. How to pass account_Id like 29, 266?

Comment: as @TimBiegeleisen said it won't work with ID's that only appear on t_acc_id like id 22 in your example

Comment: Thanks a lot and helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This query only serves the above requirement (for single account). If you want to get result for all the accounts then you need to group the records by account.

Try this(It's based on your requirement):

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN t_acc_id = 29 THEN t_acc_id 
         WHEN t_acd_id = 29 THEN t_acd_id 
       END      account_id, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN t_acd_id = 29 THEN t_amount 
             ELSE 0 
           END) rec_Amount, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN t_acc_id = 29 THEN t_amount 
             ELSE 0 
           END) pay_Amount 
FROM   tbl_transactions 
WHERE  t_acc_id = 29 
        OR t_acd_id = 29
```

Comment: Sounds great!! I thought it was an issue, :p .

Answer (score 0):

The following query takes into account the possibility that a given idea might appear only in `t_acd_Id` or `t_acc_Id`, but not both.  In this case, we would like to do a full outer join, but MySQL does not directly support this.  Instead, the first subquery in my answer obtains all unique ID values.  This is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to two other subqueries for each of the totals you want.

```
SELECT t1.accout_Id, t2.rec_Amount, t3.pay_Amount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT t_acd_Id AS accout_Id FROM tbl_transactions
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT t_acc_Id AS accout_Id FROM tbl_transactions
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t_acd_Id AS accout_Id, SUM(t_acd_Id) AS rec_Amount
    FROM tbl_transactions
    GROUP BY t_acd_Id
) t2
ON t1.accout_Id = t2.accout_Id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t_acc_Id AS accout_Id, SUM(t_acc_Id) AS pay_Amount
    FROM tbl_transactions
    GROUP BY t_acc_Id
) t3
ON t1.accout_Id = t3.accout_Id
```

**Click the link below for a running demo:**

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/643b7/1)

Comment: @sagi Look closely at his data.  Your `INNER JOIN` might leave out data in the event that an `id` only appears in `t_acd_Id` or `t_acc_Id`.

Comment: In his example it doesn't happend, and why not use full outer join in that case?

Comment: Actually, it does happen.  Look at id `22` in the `t_acc_Id` column.  And my query is not much different than yours other than that I deal with this possibility.  It adds one small step, that's all.

Comment: You're right, didn't noticed that.. fixed my answer